# Different serial numbers behind the same time value in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, date-time

I have a number of 10-minute interval time series CSV files. Sometimes there are single rows missing in the files. To complete the missing rows, I decided to search for them in Excel and insert new row values by averaging the previous and next rows.

For this purpose I have added two columns next to the existing date-time column. One for the new 10-minute date-time, the second one for comparing two date-time columns.

[image: Finding the missing row]

However, it does not work as expected and displays 0 even if the date-times are the same. To see the values behind the date-times, I set the column format to number. Apparently the numbers are actually different, but Excel rounds them up and displays the "right" date-time.

[image: Date are actually different in values]

My questions are:

1. why Excel processes the imported data differently than the ones I created by dragging and filling;
2. how can I prevent Excel from handling the date and time values incorrectly?

### Update:

The time information in CSV file does not contain milliseconds.

```
01.07.2020 00:00:00;36566463;50186;5,3;6,8;8,4;11,88;13,52;15,23;-115;-63;-27;340;522;746;277
01.07.2020 00:10:00;36566532;50186;5,3;6,4;7,5;11,95;12,7;13,78;-72;-42;-26;342;421;543;275
01.07.2020 00:20:00;36566623;50186;5,5;6,9;8,1;12,18;13,73;15,27;-115;-69;-30;368;545;747;275
01.07.2020 00:30:00;36566699;50186;5,4;6,6;7,7;11,76;13;14,54;-92;-49;-25;328;455;643;274
01.07.2020 00:40:00;36566772;50187;5,8;6,6;7,8;11,84;12,91;13,82;-72;-48;-25;340;444;552;269
01.07.2020 00:50:00;36566871;50187;6,6;7,4;8,1;13,3;14,04;14,66;-98;-78;-57;491;586;670;265
01.07.2020 01:00:00;36567002;50187;7;8;9,1;14,55;15,38;16,11;-168;-123;-94;659;783;966;261
01.07.2020 01:10:00;36567129;50187;7;7,9;8,9;14,08;15,21;16,11;-165;-113;-75;607;754;961;257
01.07.2020 01:20:00;36567285;50187;5,9;8,2;10,2;13,95;15,75;16,82;-325;-154;-69;585;924;1578;259
01.07.2020 01:30:00;36567444;50187;6,2;8,2;10,4;13,65;15,68;16,9;-356;-159;-58;541;945;1683;264
01.07.2020 01:40:00;36567631;50188;7,2;8,8;10,7;15,39;16,23;16,74;-300;-198;-120;778;1110;1533;257
01.07.2020 01:50:00;36567867;50188;6,7;9,4;11,5;13,19;16,52;18,93;-447;-286;-48;489;1400;1980;260
01.07.2020 02:00:00;36567989;50188;6,1;7,7;9,7;13,25;14,9;16,45;-251;-108;-49;491;727;1254;261
01.07.2020 02:10:00;36568122;50188;5,9;7,8;9,2;13,55;15,31;16,26;-196;-121;-56;526;790;1085;259
01.07.2020 02:20:00;36568280;50188;6,1;8,1;10,4;13,57;15,7;16,88;-332;-154;-55;529;935;1651;256
01.07.2020 02:30:00;36568452;50188;6,8;8,2;9,9;15,37;16,13;16,54;-246;-174;-113;774;1025;1315;256
01.07.2020 02:40:00;36568620;50189;6,7;8,2;10,3;14,32;15,94;16,71;-289;-168;-79;634;994;1492;256
01.07.2020 02:50:00;36568840;50189;7,3;9;10,5;15,73;16,48;16,94;-369;-251;-134;849;1306;1721;257
01.07.2020 03:00:00;36569098;50189;8,1;9,6;11,5;16,24;16,72;17,24;-433;-323;-216;1100;1531;1920;258
01.07.2020 03:10:00;36569358;50189;7,6;9,4;11,2;16,22;16,75;17,79;-445;-324;-210;1106;1544;1961;256
01.07.2020 03:20:00;36569657;50189;7,8;10;12,2;16,19;17,33;18,93;-453;-397;-211;1114;1771;1978;265
...
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like either your raw data might be including milliseconds or your calculation to add to a previous interval is not precise.

Note that if formatted to nearest minute, both of these values would appear the same, even though one is actually 10 milliseconds before the other.

[image]

You can use this format to check the time to the millisecond:

```
hh:mm:ss.000
```

EDIT1:
It seems your check column is the one with the lower of the two values in my screenshot. Please type the time in the first row of your check column (presumably B2), then use this formula in the row beneath (B3):

```
=B2+TIME(0,10,0)
```

Then drag cell B3 down to the bottom of the table. Using the function will be more precise. I hope this will fix your issue.

EDIT2:
Now that I think of it, you may have more luck by comparing one row in the original data with the next. You could use this in cell B2:

```
=(A2-A1)<>(10/(24*60))
```

This will check if A2 is not 10 minutes after A1. If this returns TRUE, then you need to insert a row. You would then drag down.

One issue for all of these checks is that each time you insert a row you have to drag down again.

Comment: I have updated my question and added a sample from the CSV data. The time values are all represented in date-time format. Using `ss.000` did not work. I tried with `hh:mm:ss.ms`, but it looks like the problem is on the microsecond scale.

Comment: Please see my edit.